# sort a list of TarInfo

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, tarfile

i have a tar file but his members are not in the right order.

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("test.tar")
tar_members = tar.getmembers()[1:]


for elem in tar_members:   
    print(elem)

tar.close()
```

And if i use `tar_members.sort()` before my `for` i have the error : `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'TarInfo' and 'TarInfo'`

I try this and it's work :

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("test.tar")
tar_members = tar.getmembers()[1:]


tar_name = []

for elem in tar_members:
    tar_name.append(elem.name)

tar_name.sort()

tar_members = []
for name in tar_name:
    tar_members.append(tar.getmember(name))

for elem in tar_members:   
    print(elem)

tar.close()
```

I want to know if there is a simple way to sort the result of getmembers()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare `TarInfo` objects, but you can compare their names:

```
tar_members = sorted(tar_members, key=lambda m: m.name)
```